# How to get the second instance of repetitive word in regex?

Tags: php, regex

My string is `Add New Tax Rate,Add New Tax Rate`.

I want to get the second instance of `Tax` with regex pattern in my string and replace it.

Comment: what ave you tried so far?

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis I don't know of regex pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP's PCRE feature you can use this regex to replace only 2nd instance of `Tax`:

```
$str = 'Add New Tax Rate,Add New Tax Rate';

$repl = preg_replace('/^.*?\bTax\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\bTax\b/', 'REPLACED', $str, 1);

//=> Add New Tax Rate,Add New REPLACED Rate
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4N8w9/4)

Here `^.*?\bTax\b(*SKIP)(*F)` will match and skip first match of `Tax`.